# AFNetworking - JSONRequestOperationWithRequest success on 400 status code

Tags: iphone, ios, json, afnetworking

I'm using

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"paths/" parameters:params];

AFJSONRequestOperation *jsonRequest = [AFJSONRequestOperation
JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request,
NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
       // something to do here in case of success
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON
{ 
      // and something there in case of failure
}
```

Everything works fine, except in one case, when I receive a response with **400 status** code, and a `JSON` (valid, I've checked) containing some information about this error, as I can see using the browser.
But `JSONRequestOperationWithRequest` calls success block, and `JSON` and response are nil.
What could cause this?

Comment: If you are getting 400 status code then the failure block should be called. (I checked AFNetworking source code)

Comment: In fact in other cases the failure block is being called, only in this case success block is being called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Failure is called if the requestOperation has an associated error after finishing. Reasons for an error include the response having the incorrect Content-Type, not having an acceptable status code (2XX range, by default, but this can be changed with `AFHTTPRequestOperation +addAcceptableStatusCodes:`), or an error processing the downloaded data. This is guaranteed behavior.

You may get JSON objects in a 400 response as part of the `failure` block, and you may get a `nil` JSON in the `success`. These are both consistent with how AFNetworking works.